# Curiously Recursive Template Pattern in GCC 3.4 (MoSync to be exact)

Tags: c++, templates, linker, gcc3, mosync

I'm currently trying to write an [Artemis](http://gamadu.com/artemis/) like game component/entity system in C++. I was planning on getting this system to work with a cross platform tool for writing applications on Android and iOS called [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/).

Unfortunately MoSync currently uses an old version of GCC and when porting the library that I had been testing in Visual Studio, I got a whole bunch of errors. Most of these I could solve, but there is one bug with templates that I can't get my head around.

I wrote a small example

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
 static int type;
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
};

template <typename T>
int Base<T>::type(-1);

extern "C" int MAMain()
{
 Derived d;
 d.type = 0;
}
```

My library uses the Curiously Recursive Template Pattern for defining Components. This example compiles fine in GCC 4.4 and Visual Studio 2010. However when I try to compile this in MoSync (which uses GCC 3.4.6) I get this linker error

```
C:\MoSync\workspace\pede\main.cpp: Error: Unresolved symbol '__ZN4BaseI7DerivedE4typeE',
```

Is there a workaround to get this to work in this compiler, or will I have to find another way to define my Components?

Edit*
In fact I can make this error occur with an even simpler example:

```
template <typename T>
struct Component {
    static int t;
};

template <typename T>
int Component<T>::t(-1);

extern "C" int MAMain()
{
    Component<int>::t = 0;
}
```

Gives this error

```
C:\MoSync\workspace\Components\main.cpp:9: Error: Unresolved symbol '__ZN9ComponentIiE1tE',
```

I guess this might not have anything to do with the Curiously Recursive Template Pattern at all. What can I do to get this to compile under GCC 3.4.6?

Comment: Wow, I would really consider moving to something else, that uses actually *usable* version of GCC...

Comment: Have you tried defining the variable type before instantiating the template?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error PlasmaHH =(

Comment: I would love to use a more modern version of GCC. Apparently the guy at MoSync who wrote the back end has left and they have no idea how to upgrade the system to use gcc4...

Comment: It sounds a lot like the tool you are using has been abandoned, and as a result it is only possible for it to become more inconvenient as time goes on. The sooner you jump ship, the easier your life will be in the future!

Comment: Just for what little it's worth, CRTP stands for "Curiously *recurring* template pattern".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14761) on the gcc bugtracker, the problem is caused by specifying a default value in the static variable definition. The code should link if you remove the initialisation as so:

```
int Base<T>::type;
```

The bug report seems to have been resolved as not a bug. Despite this, your samples compile fine in GCC 4.4.

To work around this, you can use a class type with a constructor that will automatically initialise itself.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding

```
int Base<Derived>::type(-1);
```

helps ?

gcc 3.4 is really starting to be old and don't coep well with template sorcery.

Comment: I get a syntax error when I try this..
`C:\MoSync\workspace\SmallTest\main.cpp:14: error: too few template-parameter-lists`